# How to correct the Socket Exception in emulator

Tags: android, sockets, exception, android-emulator

I have written code for Client and server connectivity in android.When I run in Emulator it shows 09-16 19:04:14.783: E/ClientActivity(407): java.net.ConnectException: /10.0.2.15:8080 - Connection refused.I referred many developer.android for redirection.But it didn't work.Can anybody say the reason for this exception and how to fix this issue?
ServerActivity.java

```
                    package com.example.network;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView serverStatus;

    // default ip
    public static String SERVERIP = "";

    // designate a port
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        fst.start();
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                if (SERVERIP != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
        //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i.getHostAddress.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                            serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                        }
                    });
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                    while (true) {
                        // listen for incoming clients
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                            }
                        });

                        try {
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // do whatever you want to the front end
                                        // this is where you can be creative
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                                }
                            });
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Error");
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // gets the ip address of your phone's network
    private String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en =               NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
             // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
             serverSocket.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

}
ClientActivity.java
        package com.example.network;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText serverIp;

    private Button connectPhones;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    private boolean connected = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
                if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
                connected = true;
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);
                            // where you issue the commands
                            out.println("Hey Server!");
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.apache.android.xmpp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application  android:name="XMPPDemosApplication"
            android:label="XMPP Demo">
        <activity android:name=".XMPPClient" android:label="XMPPClient">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The manifest file is written in XML not Java, it should be called AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: There we go :) Didn't come up yet

Comment: @SmartLemon I have included my manifest.xml

Comment: @SmartLemon the coding works perfectly when the server is a phone and my client is Emulator and viceversa.It didn't work when i connect two emulators

Comment: Just looking at the client now..

Comment: Is the address valid? Run the server application, get the IP and statically add it into the code and us that to see what happens

Comment: Why is it that you are getting the port from server activity? Shouldn't you have it statically in client activity?

Comment: When i run the server,the server will be showing Listening on 10.0.2.15.Then I entered that address in client emulator.The problem persists.I guess the problem is because of the IP address resolution of emulators.Can u please give a solution for that

Comment: So you are using an emulator to do this? Hmm, it should be fine still, just could be a problem. If you are going from a emulator to a physical device your firewall maybe blocking the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add redirection to work between two emulators da!
In windows, open command prompt and type-- telnet localhost 5554 (this 5554 is the port on which ur receiving emulator is running)
now u'r Telnet gets connected to this emulator. Now type this cmd : redir add tcp:src_port:dst port
the src port refers to the machine port and the dst port refers to the emulator port to which u wanna redirect. This works fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator I would suggest for you to check you firewall settings and make sure that the emulator is an exception

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're working on a laptop, and moving from one network to another, the emulator often needs to be restarted to pick up the right network settings on the new network.